# What Unique Hardware Identity Information Can Android 12 Apps Access to the Device

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-security, android-12, hardware-id

I'm wondering what information applications can obtain regarding the hardware ID. Which device-specific credentials such as Mac Address, Bluetooth Mac Address, IMEI are accessible to user applications.

Comment: In short: none of them, without special permission, for privacy reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You can find detailed info regarding identifiers in the article:
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids

Just pay attention to changes in Android 10:

> Android 10 (API level 29) adds restrictions for non-resettable
> identifiers, which include both IMEI and serial number. Your app must
> be a **device** or **profile owner** app, have special carrier permissions, or
> have the READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE privileged permission in order to
> access these identifiers.